# Route calling method in different controller in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, routes, request

I have following Route to download xls template

```
Route::post('admin/excel/download', 'ExcelController@customTemplateDownload');
```

I have two Controllers one is `ExcelController` which is latest one. And I have another Controller `ExcelController_original` which is old one.

Both Controller have same function

```
public function customTemplateDownload(Request $request){

     dd($request->all());

     // code to download template
}
```

When download request is sent through above route, it should call function `customTemplateDownload` in `ExcelController` but its calling function `customTemplateDownload` in `ExcelController_original`.

Anyone have idea about this problem ?

Thanks in Advance,

Comment: (When download request is sent through above route, it should call function in ExcelController but its calling ExcelController)... read this line and we need some more details

Comment: check your route file... i think you have two routes(admin/excel/download)

Comment: Are this two files with differents name: ```ExcelController.php``` and ```ExcelController_original.php```? Run ```composer dump-autoload -o``` for rebuild autoload classmap.

Comment: I've already checked, and there is only one route admin/excel/download

Comment: @AndreyLutskevich Thanks man, I have problems with composer. problem solved if you post this as answer I will accept and close question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be due to classes names. Run `composer dump-autoload -o` for rebuild autoload classmap.

Answer (score 2):

If route is proper then try by clearing cache:

- regenerate autoload classes

  composer dump-autoload
- Recreate boostrap/cache/compiled.php

  php artisan optimize
- clear cache from facades

  php artisan cache:clear
- clear route cache

  php artisan route:cache
- clear view cache

  php artisan view:clear
- clear config cache

  php artisan config:cache